# Change image sizes in NSArray Function - XCode

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I'm trying to create myself a basic `iOS` app with nothing but HTML knowledge.

I added a code I found for an in-App animation but the animation's dimensions and placement are wrong. Here is the code:

```
 NSArray *imageNames = @[@"fold1.png", @"fold2.png", @"fold3.png", @"fold4.png",
                        @"fold5.png", @"fold6.png", @"fold7.png", @"fold8.png",
                        @"fold9.png", @"fold10.png", @"fold11.png", @"fold12.png",
                        @"foldclear.png"];

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < imageNames.count; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]]];
}

// Normal Animation
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 95, 86, 193)];
animationImageView.animationImages = images;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

}

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean the "animation dimension and placement are all wrong"? If you mean the position of the UIImageView is wrong, try altering the `CGRectMake()` method keeping in mind its parameters are X, Y, Width, & Height.

Comment: You can n=make the for loop simpler with Fast Enumeration: `for (NSString *name in imageNames) {`
    `[images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:name]];` `}`

Comment: I feel very dumb for that being such a simple solution, but it was a solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to change the coordinates in `CGRectMake()`.

```
CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChrisDaniels can you please mark it as a correct answer?